# Source of small deviance between SAS PROC LOGISTIC and Python sklearn LogisticRegression (unpenalized)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sas, logistic-regression

I'm trying to match the results of SAS's `PROC LOGISTIC` with `sklearn` in Python 3. SAS uses unpenalized regression, which I can achieve in `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` with the option `C = 1e9` or `penalty='none'`.

That should be the end of the story, but I still notice a small difference when I use a public [data set from UCLA](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/hsb2-4.sas7bdat) and try to replicate [their multiple regression](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/unlinked/sas-logistic/proc-logistic-and-logistic-regression-models/) of `FEMALE` and `MATH` on `hiwrite`.

This is my Python script:

```
# module imports
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# read in the data
df = pd.read_sas("~/Downloads/hsb2-4.sas7bdat")

# FE
df["hiwrite"] = df["write"] >= 52

print("\n\n")
print("Multiple Regression of Female and Math on hiwrite:")
feature_cols = ['female','math']

y=df["hiwrite"]
X=df[feature_cols]

# sklearn output
model = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = True, C = 1e9)
mdl = model.fit(X, y)
print(mdl.intercept_)
print(mdl.coef_)
```

which yields:

> ```
> Multiple Regression of Female and Math on hiwrite:
> [-10.36619688]
> [[1.63062846 0.1978864 ]]
> ```

UCLA has this result from SAS:

> ```
>              Analysis of Maximum Likelihood Estimates
>                                Standard          Wald
> Parameter    DF    Estimate       Error    Chi-Square    Pr > ChiSq
> Intercept     1    -10.3651      1.5535       44.5153        <.0001
> FEMALE        1      1.6304      0.4052       16.1922        <.0001
> MATH          1      0.1979      0.0293       45.5559        <.0001
> ```

which is close, but as you can see the intercept parameter estimate is different at the 3rd decimal place and the estimate on `female` is different at the 4th decimal place. I tried changing some of the other parameters (like `tol` and `max_iter` as well as the `solver`) but it did not change the results. I also tried the `Logit` in `statsmodel.api` - it matches `sklearn`, not SAS. R matches Python on the intercept and first coefficient, but is slightly different from both SAS and Python on the second coefficient...

*Update:* I went to SAS' community to look for answers and someone mentioned that it may be due to differences in the iterative maximum likelihood algorithm convergence. I feel like that sounds right though I've already tried to get at that with the available options in Python.

Any thoughts on the source of the error and how to make Python match SAS?

Comment: MLE tolerance level in SAS and check what Python/SciKit learn uses for the tolerance level in the MLE algorithm or whatever it's doing.

Comment: @Reeza Thanks. I don't have SAS myself, but in Python I tried changing `tol`, `solver`, and `max_iter` but they made no difference with this small data set.

Comment: Did you look up the default tolerance settings for SAS in the documentation and set Python to the same? Unfortuantely if that's different then you need to start comparing implementation details, but again all are in the documentation under details. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_logistic_details09.htm

Comment: @Reeza Thanks. Yes, I did try `tol` however to your point I just found [something](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468356/logistic-regression-loss-function-scikit-learn-vs-glmnet) that may or may not provide a clue (I was looking at the difference between R and sklearn as well for clues). I will divide into the implementation details per your advice.